# Postgresql - slow "select * from table limit 1" query

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3. I have database with one table, and this table have over 600 milions rows. When I connect to this database first query is really slow:

```
explain analyze select * from request_log limit 1;
Limit  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=61) (actual time=481439.127..481439.129 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on request_log  (cost=0.00..13996870.79 rows=651159679 width=61) (actual time=481439.123..481439.123 rows=1 loops=1)
Total runtime: 481440.488 ms
```

I don't understand that - why seq scan just don't stop after reading first row?

Comment: are there any indexes on `request_log`?

Comment: yes, I have two indexes: on pkey and on one column. Does it make any difference during this Seq Scan?

Comment: I would try adding an `order by` to the query, on the primary key, to see if using an index improves the access.

Comment: Also, is it possible that the statistics on `request_log` are out of date?

Comment: Indexes are irrelevant here. Is request_log a view rather than a table? The query-plan is exactly what you'd expect (it *does* stop after 1 row) but for some reason you have a 481 second startup time.

Comment: What is the timing if you run the query a second time?

Comment: try `explain (analyze, buffers)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you mis-reading the output from explain analyse.

The line "Limit  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=61) (actual time=481439.127..481439.129 rows=1 loops=1)" shows that it has limited the sequential scan.

If you try it without the limit

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT * FROM request_log;
```

you will (probably) see that it takes a lot longer.

The problem is something to do with data retrieval in your database.  Check your postgresql.conf file under RESOURCE USUAGE and QUERY TUNING - look for anything unusual.  Check you postgresql log for anything unusual.